# parked domain in static ip

Tags: windows-server-2003, ubuntu, web-server, dns-hosting, static-ip

we have a server with static ip . we need to park domain in this server .I hear we must install dns server| how to configure this.
what windows server 2003 solution ?
what ubuntu server solution ?

---

what about sub domain ?
can tell some  particular server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to host the DNS for this domain on that particular server.

You just need a domain registrar who will point the A records for that domain to the static IP of your server, which then just needs web server software running.